# How to build a lightning component that works with Salesforce 1 in offline mode?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, mobile

I have a requirement to capture data in offline mode and sync it when online. I do not want to use Salesforce Offline . I want to use **Salesforce1** offline , which right now has read only capabilities. So is it possible to develop a lightning component that captures data , caches it and pushes to objects when online ?

Any pointers  ? Any help is greatly appreciated ? Thanks

UPDATING

**OOPS sorry just saw the documentation , lightning pages wont be served in offline mode**

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_sf1_offline.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to somehow wire in your lightning component to use the offline storage in the Salesforce1 Mobile App, then currently there is no ready-made option.

But in the same fashion that you can build a Visualforce page as part of a Hybrid Remote mobile app, you could do the same with Lightning Components. In this case you would be building your own mobile app, that would request a Lightning Components app, which then used cordova to access device features.

If I was tackling this, I think the first approach I would take would be to fire up a hybrid remote visualforce app using Mobile SDK, then reverse-engineer the visualforce scaffolding and libraries to see if I could get the mobile app to request my lightning app.

If you get that basic scaffolding in place you could then use the SmartStore feature for your offline data.

I do know of some developers who have spoken of this, and as I said, this is not exactly what you're asking for, but it seemed worth mentioning it as an option.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I gave up on this . As suggested will roll out a quick app mostly using ionic  to see this.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_sf1_offline.htm&language=en_US

Table says clearly that lightning pages  are not available for offline use.